# xampp stopped working after connecting to work WIFI

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp, wifi

This may seem odd but this is what has happened:

I am working on a PHP project at home:

XAMPP worked fine and so did the project. It connected to the database.

I recently have lost internet at home for a brief period so have taken my laptop to work to continue with the project. However my in the browser keeps timing out. I can not connect to my database or view even a simple html page.

I have used XAMPP without an internet connection and not had a problem just lose some features that come with CDNs.

The only thing I have done between it working and not working it connected to my work WIFI.

XAMPP working fine and there are no error logs. It is just timing out

Does anyone have any ideas

Im using Netbeans but do not think this is the problem

Answer (score -1):

I looked into this with my it department. The wifi at work has security which blocks ports and other activities.